# How can I get the address of a pointer？

Tags: go

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
   var a int= 20   
   var ip *int    

   ip = &a 

   fmt.Printf("a address: %x\n", &a  )

   fmt.Printf(" the adrress that ip stored: %x\n", ip )
   /*I try to get the address of variable ip */
   fmt.Printf(" the address of ip: %d\n", &ip )

}
```

> go run a.go

result:

a address: c420016078
the adrress that ip stored: c420016078 
 the address of ip: 842350510120

my question is : is 842350510120 correct address of ip?

Comment: Yes. Why are you doubting it? Because it's "bigger" than the other pointers? You print it using decimal radix, while the rest is using hexadecimal. To print it using hexa, use `%x` verb, or `%p` (which will also add a `0x` prefix).

Comment: @icza yes.you get my point .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print addresses in a consistent base (hexadecimal), you will see the expected result. In the current versions of the Go gc compiler, the variables `i` and `pi` are allocated on the heap.

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var i int = 20
    var pi *int = &i
    fmt.Printf("%x the address of i\n", &i)
    fmt.Printf("%x the address of pi\n", &pi)
    fmt.Printf("%x the address that pi stored\n", pi)
}
```

Output:

```
c00008e010 the address of i
c000090018 the address of pi
c00008e010 the address that pi stored
```

Comment: tank u.I just drunk，u get what i want to ask. thanku

Answer (score 1):

> my question is : is 842350510120 correct address of ip?

Nobody can answer this. It depends on your computer and might even change on every run of the program.

If you are asking whether `fmt.Printf("%d", &ip)` prints the address of ip: Yes.

Answer (score -1):

No, you need to print the address like %x like you did in the previous print statements. I guess, thats what confused you as the address was being read as an int.

Working code here, https://play.golang.org/p/v0UXMQ3fCkd